# Return All Historical Account Records for Accounts with Change in Corresponding Value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to select all records in a time-variant Account table for each account with a change in an associated value (e.g. the maturity date). A change in the value will result in the most recent record for an account being end-dated and a new record (containing a new effective date of the following day) being created. The most recent records for accounts in this table have an end-date of 12/31/9000.

For instance, in the below illustration, account 44444444 would not be included in my query result set since it hasn't had a change in the value (and thus also has no additional records aside from the original); however, the other accounts have multiple changes in values (and multiple records), so I would want to see those returned.

[image: Illustration]

I've tried using the row_num function, as well as a reflexive join, but for some reason I'm not getting the expected results. What are some ways to obtain the results I need?

Note: The primary key for this table includes the acct_id and eff_dt. Also, I'm using PostgreSQL in a Greenplum environment.

---

Here are two types of queries I tried to use but which produced problematic results:

[Query 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPfsT.png)
[Query 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUc2y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only the accounts, use aggregation:

```
select acct_id
from t
group by acct_id
having min(value) <> max(value);
```

Based on your description, you could also use `count(*) >`.

If you want the original records, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by acct_id) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Gordon. Much appreciated.

Comment: Let's say that there are multiple conditions other than just changes in the entry date which would cause a new record to be created for an account, but we are interested only in accounts where the entry date has changed. How would we modify your second query (with the window function) to pull all records for those accounts where the entry date has changed?

Comment: @FirestormDelta . . . It is only possible to answer the question that is actually asked.  If you have *another* question, ask it as *another* question, not in a comment.

Comment: My apologies, I should have made my question more specific and realized I left out that last requirement. I've restated the question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49201957/return-all-historical-records-for-accounts-with-change-in-specific-associated-va