# Return All Historical Records for Accounts with Change in Specific Associated Value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to select all records in a time-variant Account table for each account with a change in an associated value (e.g. the maturity date). A change in the value will result in the most recent record for an account being end-dated and a new record (containing a new effective date of the following day) being created. The most recent records for accounts in this table have an end-date of 12/31/9000.

For instance, in the below illustration, account 44444444 would not be included in my query result set since it hasn't had a change in the value (and thus also has no additional records aside from the original); however, the other accounts have multiple changes in values (and multiple records), so I would want to see those returned.

Also, the table has a number of other fields (columns) not included below but for which changes in the values for these fields can trigger a new record being created; however, I only want to retrieve all records for those accounts where the figure in the “value” column has changed. What are some ways to obtain the results I need?

[image: Capture]

Note: The primary key for this table includes the acct_id and eff_dt, and I'm using PostgreSQL within a Greenplum environment.

---

Here are two types of queries I tried to use but which produced problematic results:

[Query 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFFFW.png)
[Query 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8o1oX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want window functions to compare the value:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(t.value) over (partition by t.acct_id) as min_value,
             max(t.value) over (partition by t.acct_id) as max_value
      from t
     ) t
where min_value <> max_value;
```